# Should we use NoActionBar theme or not?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments

I am creating an android application which has only **one Activity and multiple fragments** in it using NavigationGraph and other Jetpack libraries as well. My Issue is that as per the design provided for the app it has different types of Toolbar in different screen (some has multi line text, some has a proper button(not toolbar menu) inside the toolbar, and some search toolbar).

In a way you can say it multiple type of toolbar in different screens.

So, What approach should I follow :

1. Just customize the toolbar where ever it is different from default one

Note: I am having a tough time using this approach as I am unable to customize the toolbar  cause the line `(activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(binding.customToolbar)` doesn't have any effect

2. Use NoActionBar theme in app and manually adding toolbar in all the screen

I haven't tried this approach, just wanted some insight before working on it

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Support app bar variations guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#support_app_bar_variations), it is recommended to use a `NoActionBar` theme and have each screen have its own `Toolbar`. In this case, you would not use `setSupportActionBar()` at all (instead, using the [toolbar APIs directly](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/appbar#fragment) if you want to use menu items, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    You just  remove the toolbar and add your custom toolbar it having two methods 
    1.add theme in `mainfest` file like this
     <style name="`AppTheme.NoActionBar`">
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        </style>
    Add this line in your manifest likethis
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Product"
    2. Method is add this line in your activity
      getSupportActionBar().hide();
Thank you
```